# Create unique, human-readable identifiers (hash?) for strings in R

Tags: r, hash, digest

I have a set of strings that I need to convert to unique, short identifiers.

Identifiers should be:

- unique; it should be *very* unlikely that different strings result in same identifiers
- automatic; I don't want to create / hardcode manual identifiers (as in: Id212).
- as short as possible; these identifiers will have to be as short as possible, because they have to be entered by humans.
- they don't have to be hex, all letters and numbers would work
- should be easily handled by humans, but not be human-readable (they should *not* make any kind of *sense*).
- *cryptographic security*, aside from uniqueness, is not a concern

I thought about doing this:

```
string <- c("this is obviously an amateur")
library(digest)
hash <- digest(object = string, algo = "crc32", serialize = FALSE)
```

resulting in "ac32ed9d".

My questions are:

- can I make this string even shorter by using the entire alphabet?
- there seems to be a concern about `crc32` causing clashes – will that be a problem with, say 500 quite long sentences?
- Is this, generally, a sound way to go about the problem?

Comment: Would `abbreviate` be sufficient?

Comment: thanks for the pointer @hrbrmstr!
`abbreviate` won't help much because its abbreviations _make sense_ (they should not, that might distract participants).
Also, the strings will sometimes change in subtle, but relevant ways, and I fear that `abbreviate` may result in same abbreviations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with R but I will try to give an answer to the general problem.

In general a hash code generates a number from a given String or object (o) within a given range `[0..R]`.

`N = hash(o,R)`

You can use this number to produce a short string as follows:

1. Choose a range of characters (alphabeth) to choose from e.g. `[A-Z,a-z,0-9]`. Denote its size by L (e.g. L=62)
2. Calculate the base-L representation of N. We get a series of digits `a_1,...,a_k` where each `a_i` is a number in [0 .. L-1]
3. Map each digit its representing character: `0 -> A, 1 -> B, ..., 62 -> 9`

You can truncate the resulting digit sequence at a length K of your choice.

There is a fundamental tradeoff between the number of available sequences and the collision probability. When you use a good hash function you can assume the number N to be uniformly distributed within the range. When you have selected an alphabet of L characters and a sequence length of K the collision probability is (1/L)^K.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, @Heinrich Hartmann!
I ended up just going with the 8 digit hash out in the above – there are same functions in R to change the base of a number (I'd go for base-36), but they all seem to error out because the number ist too large, if I don't split it up first.
8 digits will do for now.
I'll look into the collision probability later to see decide whether I can just truncate the hex hash.
I don't have a _lot_ of items (200) for now, but a collision might be pretty bad for other researchers here.